# check if argument is a valid date time in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a bash shell script in Linux, this program will accept a `date` `08-FEB-18 11.45.18.844 AM` as a parameter.

I am wondering if there is a simply way to check if the `date` `time` is valid?

Comment: Use `date -d` for that. But this format won't be accepted

Comment: @devops Do you need to just check the format, or that it's a valid time?

Comment: I want to check both datetime should be valid as well.

Comment: Are you limited to POSIX shell or do you have bash/zsh/ksh available?

Comment: I have edited my question. I am writing a bash shell script.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a bit creative since you have bash and map the date string into an array which can then be easily parsed with `date -d` (and the help of another associative array). Once the date/time is mapped to array elements and converted to seconds since epoch with `date -d`, you simply check the return of the date command to determine if the conversion succeeded or failed. Handle the return appropriately:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -n "$1" ] || {    ## validate one argument given
    printf "error: insufficient input\nusage: %s dd-mmm-yy hh.mm.ss.ms\n" \
    "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

oifs="$IFS"         ## save original Internal Field Separator
IFS=$' \t\n-.';     ## set IFS to break on - or .

dt=( $(echo $1) )   ## separate date into indexed array

[ "${#dt[@]}" -lt '7' ] && {    ## check all 7 components present
    printf "error: date doesn't match dd-mmm-yy hh.mm.ss.ms format\n"
    exit 1
}

IFS="$oifs"         ## reset original IFS

## create associative array mapping months to numerics
declare -A mo=(
    [JAN]=1
    [FEB]=2
    [MAR]=3
    [APR]=4
    [MAY]=5
    [JUN]=6
    [JUL]=7
    [AUG]=8
    [SEP]=9
    [OCT]=10
    [NOV]=11
    [DEC]=12
)

## any date after 30 considerd 1930, else considered 2000
[ "${dt[2]}" -gt '30' ] && dt[2]=$((${dt[2]} + 1000)) || \
dt[2]=$((${dt[2]} + 2000))

## use date to convert array contents to seconds since epoch
epochsec=$( date -d "${dt[2]}-${mo[${dt[1]}]}-${dt[0]} \
                    ${dt[3]}:${dt[4]}:${dt[5]}.${dt[6]}" +%s )

if [ "$?" -ne '0' ]; then   ## check if last return was error
    printf "error: invalid date.\n"
else    ## output good date
    printf "date: %s\n" "$(date -d @$epochsec)"
fi
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash chkcustomdt.sh "08-FEB-18 11.45.18.844"
date: Thu Feb  8 11:45:18 CST 2018
```

There are a lot of ways to approach this, this was just the first that came to mind.

Comment: Umm, I'm a bit unclear what you are asking, the date is output after checking it was a good date. You can easily change it to fit any of your needs. Do you need it in another format? It's quite simple to manipulate once you have a valid date (and you do). So let me know more about what you need output and I'll do my best to explain how to do it.